# Android C2DM Registration BroadcastReceiver stopped working

Tags: broadcastreceiver, android-c2dm

After working for months, my C2DM registration broadcast receiver stopped receiving broadcasts to it's onReceive method.  I know google is moving to GCM.  Is the C2DM service still running or is it not working because Google turned it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C2DM is still working.  I was calling this from location services.  When this was turned off on a users phone, no push token was registered.